# How to get the data of the higher band and lower band of the Bollinger Band

Tags: teechart

I want to get the data of the higher band and lower band of the Bollinger Band because I want the difference of the two data, how could I do that? thanks.  (Teechart2011Eval & VB6)

Answer (score 0):

Having a Chart with a Candle series, you have to add a FastLine series and set it to be a Bollinger function as shown here:

```
  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

  TChart1.AddSeries scCandle
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues

  TChart1.AddSeries scFastLine
  TChart1.Series(1).SetFunction tfBollinger
  TChart1.Series(1).DataSource = TChart1.Series(0)
```

Doing it, the FastLine you created is the High Bollinger Band, and a third series (another FastLine series) is created internally to represent the Low Bollinger Band. Then, to access the High Bollinger Band values you can just do it like this:

```
TChart1.Series(1).YValues.Value(i)
```

And to access the Lower Bollinger Band, you have two ways:

1. Through the Bollinger function in the FastLine you created:

`TChart1.Series(1).FunctionType.asBollinger.LowBand.YValues.Value(i)`

1. Directly using the series index of the series created internally:

`TChart1.Series(2).YValues.Value(i)`

Comment: That means if I want to add a new series, it must be series(3) because series(2) was occupied internally, right?

Comment: In the example above, Series(0) is the source; Series(1) and Series(2) are the bollinger bands. Series(1) is the series visible in the editor and Series(2) is the internal series.